# Nested iif statement to round to nickels! Will it work? AKA Penny Rounding

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have searched the web over, and have found very little dealing with this.  I wanted to know if there are any deeper issues that I am unware of getting the results this way.  the [total] variable represents the calculated total owing.  PayAmt represents what the customer will pay when paying cash only.

```
PayAmt: FormatCurrency(
IIf(Right(Str(Round([total],2)),1)="1",[total]-1,
IIf(Right(Str([total]),1)="2",[total]-2,
IIf(Right(Str([total]),1)="3",[total]+2,
IIf(Right(Str([total]),1)="4",[total]+1,
IIf(Right(Str([total]),1)="6",[total]-1,
IIf(Right(Str([total]),1)="7",[total]-2,
IIf(Right(Str([total]),1)="8",[total]+2,
IIf(Right(Str([total]),1)="9",[total]+1,[total])))))))))/100
```

This does on its face give the results as expected, I am just not sure IF I should approach this issue this way?

0.98 - 1.02 = 1.00

1.03 - 1.07 = 1.05

Having not seen anything like this, I suspect it can't be this easy.  I just don't know why.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That logic stinks. There is absolutely no need to convert a numeric to a string to round it properly. Search this site for *round to nearest nickel*. The very first result shows you a better algorithm for doing the rounding, which can easily be implemented directly in Access SQL without a single IIF or conversion to string. All those separate IIF/Str/Round statements are going to kill your performance.

Comment: Ken, thank you.  I had looked for almost every phrase except that one, which of course turned out to be to obvious one.  With time, I promise my questions will get better.

Answer (score 0):

Never use string handling for numbers.

Here is an article about serious rounding including all necessary code for any value and data type of VBA:

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20299/Rounding-values-up-down-by-4-5-or-to-significant-figures.html)